# SGS with CM10 says sdcard is full although there is plenty of space

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, sd-card

I've been using CM10 on my SGS for almost a month now and yesterday the sdcard became full somehow although it isn't.

I can't take photos or download files.

The SD-card has plenty of space, in fact all 3 memory spaces visible in Settings-> Storage have over 500MB each.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I'd suggest checking the stats with [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) just in case.

Comment: Have you already restarted your phone? Maybe it is just a temporary problem which will be fixed with restart..

Comment: Yeah, I have restarted it a few times. Matthew: I'll give that  a go, but even the PC gives me an accurate size report and lets me copy files to it. `sdcard0`, where the DCIM folder is has over 1GB of space.

Comment: Hm, indeed Titanium Backup shows SD Card: 6.2GB (0B free). Which is odd, because the app itself was installed on the SD card. Any clues as to how it's apparently full although I can write to it from Play Store and PC USB connection? Apps are **not** installed on the external SD.

Comment: Even stranger: I've moved an app that was on the SD card to the internal memory which freed about 30MB as displayed in Titanium. Then wiped the cache of some of the apps and deleted 3 photos. Now the sd card shows as full again in Titanium. What is this?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaand now it has 900MB free after running Windows Defragmenter on the SD card connected via USB cable.

Comment: It sounds like http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29018/which-specific-storage-space-is-low-when-getting-low-space-on-samsung-galaxy which would explain that you have free space although a message tells you otherwise. On the other hand, it should not prevent you from making photos or download files, as only `/datadata` is full.

Comment: That's something else, but hugely important. Thanks again.